# no values received in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, knockout.js

I am building a small form using Knockout JS and a web service using VB.NET, the web service is to take three strings (First Name, Last Name , and Hire date and save to a database) I have tested the webservice on a regular javascript and it worked fine, but not I am trying to use Knockout JS to do the same function.

The problem is that the object that is waiting for the values using ko.observable is not receiving any value and therefore null object is sent to the web service.

here is the script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var viewModel = function (f,n,h) {

        var self = this;
        this.fName = ko.observable(f);
        this.lName = ko.observable(n);
        this.hDate = ko.observable(h);


        self.savePerson = function () {

            alert("savePerson");

            var person = {
                FirstName: self.fName,
                LastName: self.lName,
                HireDate: self.hDate

            };


            var DTO = { 'Instructor1': person };


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(DTO), //JSON.stringify(DTO),
                url: "POSTHandler.asmx/SaveInstructor",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("sucess")
                    OnSaveInstructorAjaxSucceeded(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });



            function OnSaveInstructorAjaxSucceeded(result) {

                alert(result);


            }

            function OnSaveInstructorAjaxFailed(xhr, textStatus, error) {

                alert("Error occured while getting attendees, Error Code: " + xhr.status + ". Error desc: " + xhr.statusText);
            }

        }

}


    $(document).ready(function () {
        var _vm = new viewModel("f","n","h");

        ko.applyBindings(_vm);
    });

   </script>
```

and here is the html

```
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="First Name "></asp:Label>
    <input type="text" id="fname1" data-bind="value: $root.fName()"  style="margin-left: 28px" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 11px; top: 56px; position: absolute" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
    <input type="text" id="lname1" data-bind="value: $root.lName()" style="z-index: 1; left: 107px; position: absolute" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 12px; top: 98px; position: absolute" Text="Hire Date"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="hdate1" data-bind="value: $root.hDate()" style="z-index: 1; left: 104px; top: 98px; position: absolute" />

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <br />
         <br />
         <br />
         &nbsp;


  <%--<button  id="Button1" data-bind="click: $root.savePerson" style="width: 52px" >save</button>--%>

    <input type="button" value="Save" data-bind="click: savePerson" />
         </div>




   <label id="Label4" data-bind="text: $root.fName" ></label>




</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `data: ko.toJSON(DTO)`?

Comment: yes the response is error, the var person does not get any values from the text boxes

Comment: okay. Change all your input bindings as `<input type="text" id="fname1" data-bind="value: $root.fName"  style="margin-left: 28px" />` i.e. remove `()` from observables names. and use ko.toJSON for serialization.

Comment: just tried it, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two-way data-binding doesn't work in your case because you have defined them wrong. In the html you want to bind the input's value to the observable and not to the result of observable.

You're doing this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.fName()"  />
```

But you should do this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.fName"  /> -- Note the missing parenthesis
```

However, this is only part of the problem. The other problem is that your view model contains `observables`, which are implemented as functions and therefore won't serialize with `JSON.stringify`.

The easiest way to fix this is to use either `ko.toJS`and `JSON.stringify` or `ko.toJSON`.

`ko.toJS` will traverse object graph and will produce a clean copy with properties equivalent to the observables whilst `ko.toJSON` will call `ko.toJS` internally and then will use the browser's native JSON serializer.

So in your case you can try:

```
var DTO = { 
    Instructor1: {
        FirstName: self.fName,
        LastName: self.lName,
        HireDate: self.hDate
    }
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: ko.toJSON(DTO),
    url: "POSTHandler.asmx/SaveInstructor",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("sucess")
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Or you can do the work manually without any help from knockout:

```
var DTO = { 
    Instructor1: {
        FirstName: self.fName(), // Note the parenthesis
        LastName: self.lName(), // Note the parenthesis
        HireDate: self.hDate() // Note the parenthesis
    }
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
    url: "POSTHandler.asmx/SaveInstructor",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("sucess")
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Here is a [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wweryw7a/)

---

From [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html#converting-view-model-data-to-plain-json):

> To make it easy to serialize view model data, including observables and the like, Knockout includes two helper functions:
>
> `ko.toJS` — this clones your view model’s object graph, substituting for each observable the current value of that observable, so you get a plain copy that contains only your data and no Knockout-related artifacts
>
> `ko.toJSON` — this produces a JSON string representing your view model’s data. Internally, it simply calls ko.toJS on your view model, and then uses the browser’s native JSON serializer on the result. Note: for this to work on older browsers that have no native JSON serializer (e.g., IE 7 or earlier), you must also reference the json2.js library.